# Calling a graphical matlab script from a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, matlab

I have a matlab script (that runs to several thousand lines), and includes a GUI built using GUIDE. I've added the following to /usr/bin in a file 'particle_tracker'.

```
matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -r "cd /home/sam/Dropbox/xcorr; addpath('/home/sam/Dropbox/xcorr/matlab_tracker_dist/'); GUI"
```

This works, in that I can then invoke '(particle_tracker &)' from the terminal to run it (and from a remote computer using X-forwarding over ssh). However, if I try to use this command in a bash script, the GUI will load, and as soon as it finishes loading it will terminate, closing the GUI. A minimal example exhibiting this behaviour is simply:

```
#! /bin/bash
particle_tracker
```

I've tried all sorts of combinations of `wait` and `sleep` and in all cases, as soon as the GUI has loaded, it exits. I've run out of ideas, any suggestions received with thanks.

I've been tinkering more, and it doesn't seem to be an issue on an elderly pc running 3.11 kernel, old version of Mint Debian Cinnamon, but it happens across 3 machines on the 3.16 kernel (Debian) using Cinnamon, KDE, and MATE.

Comment: As an aside, don't use `/usr/bin` for your local stuff; use `/usr/local/bin`. The system itself maintains system locations - you should assume it could be wiped in an update, although this particular scenario is unlikely in practice.

Comment: Maybe put `uiwait()` at the end of your script.

Comment: That appears to have no effect; I still get the same behaviour.